# Asp.net Razor, Syntax error - onclick event parameter

Tags: razor

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteMember(@Model.ID, '@ViewBag.returnUrl')"/>
```

That code has 4 errors, 2 syntax error and 2 Unterminated string constant.

What should I do to fix these errors?

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could break it out in a an `Html.Raw` Call:

```
<input type="button"
       value="Delete"
       onclick="@(Html.Raw(String.Format("deleteMember({0}, '{1}')",
           Model.ID,
           Html.Encode(ViewBag.returnUrl)
       )))"
/>
```

Or assign it to a `string` first, then reference that variable in the attribute.

```
@{
  String onclick = String.Format("deleteMember({0}, '{1}')",
      Model.ID, Html.Encode(ViewBag.returnUrl));
}
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="@onclick" />
```

Third option is to separate concerns; Keep markup and scripts separate. [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15617410/298053) beat me to it, but something like:

```
<input type="button" value="delete"
    data-task="delete" data-id="@Model.ID" data-returnurl="@ViewBag.returnUrl" />

<!-- .... -->

<script>
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
  for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++){
    if (buttons[b].type != 'button') continue;
    switch (buttons[b].getAttribute('data-task') || ''){
      case 'delete':
        // read data-id & data-returnurl. Do something with them, and
        // move on.
        break;

      // other actions
      case 'add':
      case 'update':
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Though it's strange the first parenthesis messes with razor (even though it's declared in an attribute). I wouldn't expect this behavior myself.

Comment: Nice Solution for passing parameter through onclick event

Answer (score 1):

It's more a bug in VS than anything else.

It think it would still render as you would expect.

I like Brad's solution.

Another recommended option is to pop your values into [data-dash](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) attributes and use something like jQuery to pass the data-dash values to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it would be assigning the values to javascript variables and using them in the call of the method.

```
<script>
  var memberId = '@Model.ID';
  var returnUrl = '@ViewBag.returnUrl';
</script>

<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteMember(memberId, returnUrl)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way too to pass the parameter in the function

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.SubscriptionType,
   new SelectList(Model.DefaultPlanName, "value", "displayText"),
   new { @onclick = "Testnew('"+Model.CreationTime+"' )",
    @class = "form-control selectpicker" })
```